# How can I get my extbase extension to parse ajax requests while using RealURL

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x, realurl

First I apologize for the terrible question name.

I'm developing an extbase extension which will display records via AJAX.

When the AJAX request is sent using index.php=(number), like `http://example.com/index.php=5?type=1234&etc...`, the proper response is returned.

When the request is sent with a RealURL link, like `http://example.com/about-us/some-page/?type=1234&etc...`, the entire contents of /about-us/some-page/ are returned (without the records that were being requested).

To clarify a few things, the extension worked before I activated RealURL, and it returns the correct results with RealURL active, if I edit the request to not use the RealURL link.

It seems that RealURL is causing Typo3 to completely ignore the type parameter, as I've tried placing content directly inside my typoscript, where I define the pagetype, and it doesn't render.

I've also tried placing some extra "junk" parameters in from of "type" in the request, just to see if it was the first parameter being ignored, but that didn't work.

So, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

## EDIT

Our server administrator has changed the webserver rewrite rules, and now it works fine. That may have been the only issue from the beginning.

Comment: Just a suggestion: did you try to define a `fileName` section in [RealURL configuration](https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Configuration-reference#filenameindexkeyvalues) with your custom type?

Comment: @ViktorLivakivskyi - I tried that, and it didn't fix the problem, although it did change the nature of my error. Instead of loading the entire page again, it loaded the contents of my plugin again.
For the time being, I'm working around this by re-writing the link using javascript.